# Focus-hook: attenuate colours when losing focus

Tags: frames, hooks, focus

How can I use the focus hooks to attenuate all colours in visible buffers when the Emacs frame loses focus?

I tried using the following code:

```
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(100 80))
```

To make the frame become translucent, but it would flicker when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (apparently that's because I let GNOME highlight the mouse cursor when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

Making the frame transparent isn't what I want anyway.  Is it possible to desaturate all colours instead?

**EDIT:**  a less ambitious goal is to change/attenuate the colours of the mode line on focus change and restore them to normal when focus returns.  With two monitors I often find myself typing into the void when Emacs is displayed but not focussed, so I need some better visual indicator of focus.

Comment: While this Emacs feature sounds undeniably cool, I think it would be better to leave such a thing to the compositor you're using, `compton` for instance can dim inactive windows.

Comment: Well, I suppose that's one way to do it (and probably the right way to do it), but I don't really want this for any other window/application except for Emacs.  I guess I'd be happy with changing the colour of the modeline on focus change.

Answer (score 5):

See if `auto-dim-other-buffers-mode` works for you.

Out of the box it dims frames when they lose focus as well as buffers when they lose `current-buffer` status.

It's available on MELPA.  Source here:
https://github.com/mina86/auto-dim-other-buffers.el

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  See function `doremi-increment-color` in library [`doremi-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/doremi-frm.el).

In this case, you want to use a negative `INCREMENT` argument and specify `s` (for saturation) as the `COMPONENT` argument to increment (decrement, in this case).

You would call **`doremi-increment-color`** on any color of any UI feature you like (or on all of them), to calculate a less saturated version of the color.  See also function `hexrgb-increment-saturation` in library [`hexrgb.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hexrgb.el).

You can get an interactive idea of applying this across the board by using command `doremi-all-faces-bg+` or `doremi-all-frames-bg+` (or the same, with `fg+` instead of `bg+`).

More **Do Re Mi** color-changing described [*here*](http://www.emacswiki.org/DoReMi#OneSolution).

---

With respect to your request about dynamically desaturating and saturating the mode line: See, for example, function `1on1-color-minibuffer-frame-on-setup` in library [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el), which does the same kind of thing for a standalone minibuffer frame. It uses function `hexrgb-increment-hue`, but you would use **`hexrgb-increment-saturation`** instead (or `doremi-increment-color`).

This is the meat of that function:

```el
(set-background-color (hexrgb-increment-hue ; Change bg hue slightly.
                       (frame-parameter nil 'background-color)
                       1on1-color-minibuffer-frame-on-setup-increment))
```

Answer (score 1):

Different answer based on your edit.

If you just want to change the mode line, check out what the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Standard-Faces.html) has to say about `mode-line-inactive` face.

> Like mode-line, but used for mode lines of the windows other than the selected one (if mode-line-in-non-selected-windows is non-nil). This face inherits from mode-line, so changes in that face affect mode lines in all windows.

You could make `mode-line` have a bright red background and `mode-line-inactive` a bland grey background, for instance.